# Mondrian: null pointer exception when running MDX query for a role

Tags: mdx, olap, pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I'm getting the following exception while running the MDX query "`select {[Measures].[X]} on columns from [Metrics] where [Time].[2013].[May2013]`". But there is no exception when i run with admin role. let me know if there is any issue with Role section below or how to resolve this.

## Role segment in the xml

```xml
<Role name="test_role">
   <SchemaGrant access="none">
      <CubeGrant cube="Metrics" access="all">
           <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Cmp]"  rollupPolicy="partial" topLevel="[Cmp].[Cmp]" bottomLevel="[Cmp].[Cmp]" access="custom">
               <MemberGrant member="[Cmp]" access="none"/>
               <MemberGrant member="[Cmp].[X]" access="none"/>
               <MemberGrant member="[Cmp].[Y]" access="all" />
           </HierarchyGrant>
       </CubeGrant>
   </SchemaGrant>
</Role>
```

## Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapHierarchy$LimitedRollupMember.<init>(RolapHierarchy.java:1333)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapHierarchy$LimitedRollupSubstitutingMemberReader.substitute(RolapHierarchy.java:1429)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapHierarchy$LimitedRollupSubstitutingMemberReader.substitute(RolapHierarchy.java:1461)
    at mondrian.rolap.SubstitutingMemberReader.getDefaultMember(SubstitutingMemberReader.java:192)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaReader.getHierarchyDefaultMember(RolapSchemaReader.java:608)
    at mondrian.olap.DelegatingSchemaReader.getHierarchyDefaultMember(DelegatingSchemaReader.java:203)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapEvaluatorRoot.<init>(RolapEvaluatorRoot.java:93)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapEvaluatorRoot.<init>(RolapEvaluatorRoot.java:78)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapResult$RolapResultEvaluatorRoot.<init>(RolapResult.java:1477)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapResult.<init>(RolapResult.java:85)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapUtil.createEvaluator(RolapUtil.java:636)
    at mondrian.olap.Query.resolve(Query.java:448)
    at mondrian.olap.Query.<init>(Query.java:200)
    at mondrian.olap.Query.<init>(Query.java:161)
    at mondrian.olap.Parser$FactoryImpl.makeQuery(Parser.java:927)
    at mondrian.parser.MdxParserImpl.selectStatement(MdxParserImpl.java:1241)
    at mondrian.parser.MdxParserImpl.statement(MdxParserImpl.java:1074)
    at mondrian.parser.MdxParserImpl.statementEof(MdxParserImpl.java:188)
    at mondrian.parser.JavaccParserValidatorImpl.parseInternal(JavaccParserValidatorImpl.java:57)
    at mondrian.olap.ConnectionBase.parseStatement(ConnectionBase.java:96)
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please file it in Mondrian's bug tracking system at http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/mondrian

Comment: Filed on mondrian jira. http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-1652. Thanks